# Какой Линукс можно установить из-под Винды?

Tags: windows, linux

Есть ноутбук без дисковода на котором стоит Windows 7. Задача - нужно из-под винды поставить линукс, но только не убунту. Какой дистрибутив Линукса станет без проблем из-под Винды?

Comment: Virtualbox + образ какого-нибудь дебиана. С гипер-ви могут быть проблемы, хотя конкретно в данный момент на локалки все спокойно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

из под винды, на виртуалку. Да любой, даже мак ос и BeOS, QNX, FreeBSD.... и т.д.
А если серьзно, то если есть usb то с флешки хоть что ставь. если BIOS поддерживает загрузку с USB.